# What mobile tools should I use in my project?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, mobile

I'm relatively new in mobile development, but I'm really familiar with HTML5. I have a project, wich will be used in pubs, where the customer orders the bar through his cell phone. Some informations:

- The bar will have a local server to receive the requests (it will work in local network)
- The clients application will have live a chat, so the customers can meet new people in the same bar :). However, the chat server will be online (the customer will need internet to access this functionality)
- The application will likely use push notifications and maybe perform some simple background processing.
- The application should be Cross Platform.

So what would be the ideal technology to use? Cordova? PhoneGap? Intel XDK? Xamarin? Embarcadero? Should I also use WebSockets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So phonegap/XDK is really the same a cordova and they're all fantastic.  Phonegap and XDK are just... implementations of Cordova.  Phone gap can do everything you want it to.  I've used phonegap to link multiple phones to a server(and each other) for a grocery deals app.

I would hold off on websockets(though they technically can do what you want).  They're not the most maintainable or easiest to set up.

I've explored Xamarin a year ago and it looked like it would work for my(and your) applications.  However, it seemed to be completely tied to the .NET framework.  So if you don't mind being led by the nose for all you're profits...

I have no direct experience with Embarcadero, but I've now signed up for a trial due to this post.

Sources:  2013-2016 Mobile developer---successful and lucrative project completion

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Well ... what are the downsides of WebSockets? Could a local, low-processing server handle a large number of requests using WebSockets?

Comment: @CarlosSouza There's no reason not to use web sockets, and you don't need big iron to support it-when done right they're easily horizontally scalable if it comes to that.

Comment: @CarlosSouza you could even use websockets with a flavor of Cordova.  Dave is right that websockets are lightweight.  But i wouldn't use websockets alone(And I doubt that's what he's suggesting).  You can upgrade your cordova app to use websockets with cordova, but I think a simple server-side "webpage" displayed as if it were an application(easily masked) would be your easiest successful path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about all the technologies you asked but I have worked with cordova and accomplished all the requirements for your app. It can be a good option. I'm not very familiar with other tech

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try do do this with Cordova! But how about the WebSocks? Is it possible to do with Cordova?